# Pywin32 not saving attachments from Outlook (Restrict.Attachements)

Tags: python, winapi, outlook, pywin32

I am trying to download attachments from a particular sender in my Outlook inbox in python. I am using win32com.client. It seems python is finding the email I am looking for but I get the error Restrict.Attachements when trying to save. Could someone please help? Thank you

Python: 3.6.12 64bit

```
import win32com.client as clt
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


outlook = clt.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items
messages = messages.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = testmail@testemail.com")

received_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=5)
received_dt = received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')

for message in list(messages):
    try:
        s = message.sender
        for attachement in messages.Attachments:
            attachement.SaveASFile(os.pah.join("C:/Users/me/Desktop/", attachement.FileName))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

EDIT: I confirm the code finds the correct email, but in the loop it goes through the exception

```
>>> for message in list(messages):
...     try:
...         s = message.sender
...         for attachement in messages.Attachments:
...             attachement.SaveASFile(os.pah.join("C:/Users/me/Desktop/", attachement.FileName))
...     except Exception as e:
...         print(message.Subject, "Error: ", e)
...
TestMail Error:  Restrict.Attachments
```

Comment: What is "Restrict.Attachements"? Your only restriction is for the sender email, and you might want to enclose the value in single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `message` object for getting attachments, not the `messages` one. In the code I see the following lines:

```
 for attachement in messages.Attachments:
            attachement.SaveASFile(os.pah.join("C:/Users/me/Desktop/", attachement.FileName))
```

Instead, you need to use the following code:

```
 for attachement in message.Attachments:
            attachement.SaveASFile(os.pah.join("C:/Users/me/Desktop/", attachement.FileName))
```